# How to set values of selectized fields with results from ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, selectize.js

I've seen tons of threads on how to set a default value for select boxes I [selectize](http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/), but how do you set the value of a selectized select box with the value I get back from an ajax call?

My function looks like this:

```
$('#import_search').change(function(){
    $.ajax({ 
        url: 'import_ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { import_search: $('#import_search option:selected').val() },
        dataType: 'text',
        timeout: 60000,
        success: function(data) {
            var result = JSON.parse(data);  
            var project = result['selected_project'];
            $.each(result.data[0], function(key, value) { 
                $('#' + key).val(value);
         ->   //$('#' + whatever the new selectize ID is).setValue(value from db)
            });
        }
    }); 
});


....
//selectize the select boxes
$('#Customer').selectize({
    create: true,
    sortField: 'text'
});
```

I made it easy because the IDs of my fields match the column names in the database,

I.E the `$('#' + key).val(value);` line.

So when I get something back that has a `Customers` key, how do I set the value of the selectized customers select box to the value I get back from the ajax call?

The select boxes are selectized on load and are populated correctly from stuff from the database, this is a function to "import" settings from a previous project and pre-set everything for the user based on the selected project.

I'm not looking to add any new values, the values will already be in the selectized select boxes as "options", all I need to do is set them to what I get from the ajax call, they will always have a match because they're initially set from queries to the db.

I've tried `setValue()` but I'm not sure I'm doing it right. Please help!

This is a question specifically about the `selectize` jquery add-on, selectize changes the class, id, lots of things on whichever specific field. It's not the same question as the one proposed as a duplicate.

-EDIT-
I've modified my script, here's what I have so far.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#import_search').change(function(){
        var $select = $('#Customer').selectize();
        var selectize = $select[0].selectize;
        $.ajax({ 
            url: 'import_ajax.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { import_search: $('#import_search option:selected').val() },
            dataType: 'text',
            timeout: 60000,
            success: function(data) {
                var result = JSON.parse(data);  
                var project = result['selected_project'];
                $.each(result.data[0], function(key, value) { 
                    $('#' + key).val(value);
                    if (selectizeInstances[key]) {
                        alert(selectizeInstances[key]);
                        selectizeInstances[key].setValue(value);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });     
    var selectizeInstances = [];
    var selectizeControl = $('#Customer').selectize({
        create: true,
        sortField: 'text'
        });
    selectizeInstances['Customer'] = selectizeControl[0].selectize; 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that the `$('#import_search').change(function(){...` happens after the DOM is ready (e.g. in the callback function for `$(document).ready()`.

To call *setValue()* on the selectize control, it appears we need to capture an instance of the control. Per [the api documentation](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/api.md#user-content-selectize-api), we can do this like in the following example:

```
var selectizeInstances = [];
var selectizeControl = $('#Customer').selectize({
    create: true,
    sortField: 'text'
});
selectizeInstances['Customer'] = selectizeControl[0].selectize;
```

Then replace the line:

```
//$('#' + whatever the new selectize ID is).setValue(value from db)
```

With a check like this:

```
if (selectizeInstances[key]) {
    selectizeInstances[key].setValue(value);
}
```

Try [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FByYqMCc8mnfppsl1Sv8?p=preview) - change the *search method* select list to see the value of the *Customer* select input changed.

Or this example should demonstrate the technique, but without the AJAX requestion:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#import_search').change(function() {
    var index = $(this).val();
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(Object.keys(selectizeInstances), function(key) {
      var indexOptions = Object.keys(selectizeInstances['Customer'].options);
      if (selectizeInstances[key]) {
        var value = indexOptions[index];
        $('#' + key).val(value);
        selectizeInstances[key].setValue(value);
      }
    });
  });
  //store the reference to the selectize control in an array so it can be utilized dynamically later:
  var selectizeInstances = [];
  var selectizeControl = $('#Customer').selectize({
    create: true,
    sortField: 'text'
  });
  selectizeInstances['Customer'] = selectizeControl[0].selectize;
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.9.0/css/selectize.default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.9.0/js/standalone/selectize.js"></script>
<div>
  Search method:
  <select id="import_search">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
</div>

Customer:
<select id="Customer">
  <option value="cat">Cat</option>
  <option value="dog">Dog</option>
  <option value="rat">Rat</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The function works, this question is specifically about changing the value of select boxes that have been [selectized](http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) automatically with an ajax call.

Comment: Thanks a ton for such an in-depth answer, I'm trying to piece it together right now. There's no errors though so I'm confused as to where it's going wrong.

Comment: Could you show me how to do it with the ajax call? I'll show you what I have so far in an edit.

Comment: I updated the [plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/FByYqMCc8mnfppsl1Sv8?p=preview) which still utilizes the AJAX request

Comment: Awesome, let me try it out.

Comment: the ajax and everything is working, but it's still not populating the selectized control with the value for some reason. I tried `alert`ing both the `selectizeInstances[key]` and the `selectizeInstances[value]` and the outputs were `[object Object]` and `undefined` respectively.

Comment: let us continue this discussion [in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128429/jquery-ajax-problems)

Comment: chat is blacklisted at my company unfortunately, if you're online later I'll let you know when I'm on a different computer. Thanks again!

Comment: okay - I updated the plunker to have some more debugging - can you try adding more of your code to the plunker to see if it works in that style?

Comment: I added a div with an id of `'#console'` and when it got to customer, it output this:
    `setting Customer to Customer name

selectizeInstances[Customer].setValue: function (value, silent) { var events = silent ? [] : ['change']; debounce_events(this, events, function() { this.clear(silent); this.addItems(value, silent); }); }`
So the key value pair is correct but the value from the db did not get selected and I'm not entirely sure what I'm looking at with this setValue function, there's not many examples on the selectize API documentation

Comment: alright - what types of values are set on the `value` attribute of the `option` tags? integers? strings? objects? BTW I only really added the logging to `<div id="console"></div>` as an alternate to [console.log()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) which is how I normally debug JS apps

Comment: My customer element looks something like this: 
`<label for="Customer">
      <span>Customer:</span>
     </label>
     <div style="width: 210px">
     <select name="Customer" id="Customer" class="select">
      <?php 
       $Customer_query = "SELECT * FROM Customer;";
       $Customer_result = $mysqli->query($Customer_query);
       while($row = $Customer_result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo '<option>' . $row['Customer_Name'] . '</option>';
       }
      ?>
     </select>
     </div>` sorry for it being hideously ugly.

Comment: so to answer your question, I don't think I have anything in the value attribute.

Comment: well then it might be difficult to discern what value _has_ been selected so I suggest you set a _value_ attribute on the [option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) tags... e.g if you have a *Customer_id* field in your table, you could do: `echo '<option value="' . $row['Customer_id'] . '">' . $row['Customer_Name'] . '</option>';` That way - when the form is submitted (via traditional GET/POST, or via AJAX) the value for _Customer_ will have a value...

Comment: I feel like such an idiot, it was something with my database, not the script.. thank you SO much for all your continued help, you're awesome!

Comment: No worries - like some people say: "_Probody is nerfect_"... Cheers!